# Ubuntu 20.04 icons are grey

Tags: icons, 20.04

For some reason, after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04, the icons (in the Files app) are in grey instead of colored (as showcased by Ubuntu).
Any ideas on how to turn them colored?

[image]

Comment: Install `gnome-tweaks` and use a different theme.

Comment: Jos - Thank you, this seemed to fix it https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/yaru-theme/+bug/1798984/comments/5